# Animate a point moving on a polynomial

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm new and want to animate a point that moves along the polynomial 
$s(t) = -2.7t^2 + 30t + 6.5$. I've seen examples for polar and parametric plots, but I haven't seen examples of polynomials.

Comment: "I've seen examples" - where did you see them? They should not be too hard to modify for your particular case.

Comment: you can use the `ParametricPlot` examples using `{t, s[t]}` as the first argument.

Comment: Do you mean something like `Animate[Show[Plot[s[t], {t, -20, 20}], Graphics[{PointSize[Medium], Point[{u, s[u]}]}]], {u, -20, 20}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not too hard to do. To run the animation, you need to open the animation controls by clicking on the plus button on the righthand end of the slider.

```
s[t_] := -2.7 t^2 + 30 t + 6.5
```

This is the point that will move along `s[t]`.

```
pt[t_] := Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[{t, s[t]}]}]
```

Want to limit the plot to values of `s[t]` that are positive.

```
tmax = Max @@ Solve[s[t] == 0, t][[All, 1, 2]]
```

> `11.3237`

Here the `Manipulate` code that will allow for both manual and automatic movement (animation) of the point.

```
Manipulate[
  Show[plot, pt[t]],
  {{t, 0}, 0, tmax, .1, AppearanceElements -> All},
  {{plot, Plot[s[t], {t, 0, tmax}, ImageSize -> 5 72]}, None}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

```
s[t_] := -2.7 t^2 + 30 t + 6.5;
Dynamic @ Plot[-2.7 t^2 + 30 t + 6.5, {t, 0, 15}, 
  Mesh -> {{Clock[{0, 15}, 2, 2]}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red]]
```

[image]

Goes through the range 0 to 15 every 2 seconds and stops after 2 iterations.